# First Difference Merge back in Dataframe

Tags: python, merge, concatenation, dataframe

I have a data frame with multiple economic time series and I want to create 1st to 4th order difference of these series and merge it back to same data frame in python. As an example this is how I want to see any given series.

```
  GDP    first_diff  second_diff  third_diff  fourth_diff
  2.03              
  2.54     0.51         
  3.09     0.55        1.06     
  3.34     0.25        0.8          1.31    
  3.76     0.42        0.67         1.22        1.73
  3.89     0.13        0.55         0.8         1.35
  4.10     0.21        0.34         0.76        1.01
  4.20     0.10        0.31         0.44        0.86
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this:

df['first_diff']=df['GDP']-df['GDP'].shift(1)

df['second_diff']=df['GDP']-df['GDP'].shift(2)

and so on...where 'df' is name of your DataFrame